# onWillPop - Future<bool>Function(BuildContext) can not be assigned to parameter type Future<bool>Function()

Tags: flutter, dart

Please help me in solving this error in my flutter application:

```
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

      Future<bool> _onBackPressed(BuildContext context) {

        return showDialog(
            context:context,builder:(BuildContext context)=>AlertDialog(title: Text('Exit'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton( child:Text('NO'),onPressed: ()=>Navigator.pop(context,false)),
            FlatButton( child:Text('Yes'),onPressed: ()=>Navigator.pop(context,true))


          ],));

      }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return WillPopScope(onWillPop:_onBackPressed, // **the argument type Future<bool>Function(BuildContext) can not be assigned to parameter  Future<bool>Function()**

        child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'ListViews',
        theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.teal,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('ListViews')),
        body: BodyLayout(),
        ),
        ));
      }
    }
```

1. How can I correct this error ?
2. After writing  `Future<bool>_onBackPressed(BuildContext context) async{`  this error appears in the error box

**Error**:

```
the argument type Future<bool>Function(BuildContext) can not be assigned to parameter  Future<bool>Function()
```

Please mention if you know any better way to add **ON DOUBLE PRESS EXIT FLUTTER APP**

Answer (score 8):

Well, the `onWillPop` parameter expects a `Future<bool> Function()`, but you provided a function that needs the `BuildContext` as an argument (and is thus of type `Future<bool> Function(BuildContext context)`).

The correct way is to wrap your function in another function:

```dart
WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () => _onBackPressed(context),
  child: ...
)
```

And I don't think there's a more elegant way to detect double pressing back than saving the timestamp of the last back press and comparing that to the current time when back is pressed.

Comment: thank you it worked without any error... Adding ' ()=>' & (context) helped to solve this  error..Thank you very much..