# Play a audio File in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, audio

hey i want for my app background music, that for I need to know, how to play a Audio File in Flutter, i already imported many Adio packages but no one really worked, i am new in the flutter game xD,if it's possible it should be short command and i need it for an android App.I hope someone can help me,thanks for your help.

[nearly worked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gwecn.png)

Answer (score 4):

I've been in the same situation as you. And audio is hard(so be prepared).
I did get my background-music to work after ^4 days of work (so sorry for a long answer, but that's how to gotta be). *Hoppfully* your's dosn't take that long:

First you need to add *Audio Players* to the app:

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
```

> import these in the page the audio is being played on (I recommend playing the background music from the main page (main.dart))

Then under the *Class state* you need to make the *audio-player* and *audio-cache*, as so:

```
class _YourMainPageNameState extends State<YourMainPageName> {

AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();  //add this
  AudioCache cache = new AudioCache();  //and this

@override
  Widget build [...]
```

Then whenever you want to play the audio, call

```
player = await cache.loop('assets/yourMusicFileHere');
```

And to stop it call:

```
player.stop();
```

If you want the music to start from the point that the app opens, wrap the *Scaffold* with a *WillPopScope* like so:

```
Future<bool> _willPopCallback() async {
    player = await cache.loop('assets/yourMusicFileHere');
    return true;
  }

override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return WillPopScope(onWillPop: _willPopCallback, child: new Scaffold( [...] )
}
```

Feel free to send me any errors you got, I'll be on stackOverFlow multible times a day, so I'mma answer.
I think I got everything in this comment, but somthing *might* be missing, so make sure to hit me up with that ;)

---

---

**Edit:**
I just realised that I made a mistake, I sayd that *WillPopScope* could be used to start the music when the app started, that's not true, *WillPopScope* is for when you leave the page. So it can be used to stop music when the user leaves the app.

Now for the music to start when the app is opened, we'll have to call a function when the widget-tree is being build like so:

```
Future<bool> _willPopCallback() async { 
    player.stop(); //change this
    return true;
  }

openingActions() async { //add this
    player = await cache.loop('assets/yourMusicFileHere.mp3'); //add this
  } //add this

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    openingActions();
    return WillPopScope(onWillPop: _willPopCallback, child: new Scaffold( [...] )
```

You might run into issues where the music is being played twice, then you need to add a security-check when you play the music, like this:

```
 bool isPlaying = false;

 Future<bool> _willPopCallback() async { //change this whole thing
    if(isPlaying == false) {
      setState(() { 
        isPlaying = true;
      });
      player.stop();
    }
   return true;
  }
```

- Thanks - Tobias

Comment: dude your comlpetly in the Bill Gates mode, you helped me a lot but i still have one problem i put 2 screenshots in my post , if i make _willPopCallback(), in a Button it works but if i make it like you said "return WillPopScope(onWillPop: _willPopCallback," it don´t work , i think the reason is it has to be _willPopCallback(), but if i make this i got the error 

"The argument type 'Future<bool>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<bool> Function()'."

maybe you can fix it with your Bill Gates brain and i love you xD

Comment: I just edited my first answer. I realised that I sayd that the WillPopScope whould play the music right away, when it's for pauseing the music when the user leaves the app. And the problem you have with the willPopCallback I am not 100% sure about (I can't get the same error). But try to look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58100060/onwillpop-futureboolfunctionbuildcontext-can-not-be-assigned-to-parameterI am not sure it's the same problem, but it might help. Otherwise just try the usale error-busting: Run Flutter clean in terminal and reopen project. Feel free to contact me again

Comment: okay now it works if i load my app, but always if i push a button the background music start agian, i posted a screen from my actuell code, i think the willpopcallback method is not right or did i something wrong

Comment: Try setting the 'isPlaying' to true as default, or set it to true in the 'openingActions' when the background music starts playing in the app-opening. This is because the music starts but the 'isPlaying' hasn't, and then the 'next' bg-music starts because the 'isPlaying' isn't on. Also I'm curious what this button does? (if its a button to turn off the background music, I can help you with that)

Comment: i started a new question for this problem maybe if you got the solution you can comment it, you helped me a lot ,so thank you